# C++: Pointer as a key in a hashtable

Tags: c++, pointers, hashtable

Are there any problems using pointers as hashtable keys during program run? (no need to store to disk and use it later as that causes obvious problems)

There are many circumstances where I need to quickly know whether an object belongs to some object manager. A quick way to check it is to store every object in an object manager in a hashtable where the object's pointer is the key to the actual object: E.g, HashTable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there are no problems. It's just like storing an `int`.

A pointer has got a value that doesn't change and that uniquely identify a resource.

There of course be problems if you don't use well your pointers, but this is another, uncorrelated thing.

Comment: In fact, pointers can be safer than `std::string`, since those are mutable. `boost::hash` and `std::tr1::hash` are explicitly designed to work with pointers. Memory management may become complicated, though.

Comment: The only problem I see is alignment. All pointer values will point to values of same type, so all pointer values will be multiples of it. Which means that if alignment is 2, the hash function is the identity function, and the rehashing strategy is by doubling, all odd positions will be unused. The biggest the aligment the biggest the problem. If the aligment of the pointed-to type is 8, only positions that are multiples of 8 will be used.

Answer (score 0):

It should work well enough. Are you seeing any problems? Maybe you should just try and see. :)

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head - If mem space pointed to by your hashtable is deallocated without first deleting the references to mem space pointed to by your pointers, there is going to be memory leaks hanging around.